# How can I suppress command output when using backticks?

Tags: linux, git, bash, backticks

Is there a way to supress the command output for git if I use backticks in my shell script?
Here is my current code:

```
OUT=$(git status > /dev/null)
```

Thanks :)

Comment: What do you want to capture in `OUT`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you're wanting is to suppress the stderr but not the stdout since you still want the value. You could do this instead:

```
OUT=$(git status 2>/dev/null)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case some output is going to standard error:

```
OUT=$(git status > /dev/null 2>&1; echo $?)
```

Of course, this does leave open the question: what is it you want to capture in `OUT`?

[EDIT]
The above will put the return code of `git` into `$OUT`.

Comment: Then what do you want to capture in `OUT`?  This makes the backticks pointless.

Comment: @tripleee that's a question for the OP